# Can't pass a variable variable into a function in PHP since upgrading from 5.5.22 to 5.6.6?

Tags: php, variable-variables, php-5.6

This line of code worked perfectly before I upgraded, now it doesn't:

```
123: $thisRow[] = displayR(${"sR{$i}S1"}, ${"nR{$i}S1P"});
```

I get this error:

```
Undefined variable: sR1S1 in script.php on line 123
```

A workaround is to manually assign them first

```
$s = ${"sR{$i}S1"};
$n = ${"nR{$i}S1P"};
$thisRow[] = displayR($s, $n);
```

Is there anyway to get it working in a single line as before?  Does anyone know why it no longer works?

I should add that I've tried using

```
var_dump(${"sR{$i}S1"});
```

on the previous line and it IS defined, and has the value that I expect it to.

I can't find any mention of this behaviour on google or SO, I wonder if it's a bug rather than intended.

Comment: Clearly tightening up on sloppy coding practises is a bug: if a variable isn't defined when you pass it to a function, what is that function supposed to do?

Comment: [php notice undefined variable and notice undefined index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: The variables ARE defined @Mark.  I can var_dump them on the previous line and they're there, as inteded.

var_dump(${"sR{$i}S1"}) outputs a value, as expected.

Comment: Well if you consider that it's a bug, [flag it as a bug](https://bugs.php.net/) to the PHP core devs

Comment: In good time I will, but I thought I should tap into the near-infinite SO wisdom before bugging (hah) the limited resources of the PHP core devs!

Comment: However, it doesn't give any error on my 5.6.6.... or on [3v4l.org demo](http://3v4l.org/QfK0t)

Comment: The behaviour seems to be consistent across versions, see http://3v4l.org/sr9bn

Comment: Let me put it this way: using variables such as this instead of arrays reeks of terrible practice. We do not have any conclusive proof that this program *should* work, because we have no complete test case. The test cases which were reproduced above all work. Given all this, I find it more likely that your program has some bug, instead of PHP. You'll have to provide a complete reproducible example for us to be able to say otherwise.

Comment: That's a great resource that is new to me, and it's good to know that it SHOULD work.  I'll try to suss out what's gone wrong and report back.  All I know so far is that this 100% changed from working to broken when I upgraded PHP this morning...

Comment: Turns out it's an intermittent problem.  If I var_dump($sR1S1) and hit F5 it sometimes fixes everything.  And sometimes things remain fixed even when I remove the var_dump.  On my server this is.  Weirdness.  Definitely feels like a bug to me now.  Can't replicate on 3v4l.

Comment: ...which lead me to opcache.  And it seems that disabling opcache fixes this "problem" completely.  For whatever reason.

Comment: Bug report submitted, bug apparently fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is to be an opcache bug.

Disabling opcache on the file in question resumed the expected behaviour.

I submitted a (fairly useless) bug report at:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69159

Which has apparently been fixed and closed:

http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=commitdiff;h=a29b64fc1029b4121e3e9ff20901c35ad600b4da